# Отображение 3D моделей (obj, stl), используя jsc3d, в Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, 3d

столкнулся с такой проблемой, как невозможность просмотра моделей в Chrome, в то время как в Edge все корректно отображается. Сцена загружается, а сама модель просто не отображается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в параметрах запуска Chrome написать --allow-file-access-from-files и перезагрузить

Comment: вы знаете что Вы таким образом включаете ?)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не могли бы просветить

Comment: Код на любых сайтах сможет читать данные с Вашего диска..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ есть ли у вас предположение как возможно это обойти

Comment: а что вы хотите в итоге?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ , по итогу хотелось бы возможность отображения модели из папки без использования " --allow-file-access-from-files", т.к. без использования этой команды идет бесконечный поиск модели

Comment: Ви пытаетесь из локальной папки запустить веб страничку, которая считает файл с диска?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ совершенно верно

Comment: я для таких целей таскаю карманный веб сервер

Comment: @StrangerintheQ но смущает одно, chrome не отображает, ок, но почему  Edge отображает модель без проблем

Comment: ну пользуйтесь им тогда,:)